# app insights think time does not take into account think times

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am executing web tests in App Insights as availability tests.

The problem is that, those web test contain requests with certain think time.

For the tests I am doing the think time is crucial.

The problem I have is that seems that Application Insights does not take into account the think time values, so I don't see any way to pause the request calls within a web test.

Is there any way to make think times work in App Insights? Is it foreseen to solve this issue soon? Is there any recommendation or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered [here on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/60eff7e8-56b7-434b-845c-2aba4d35cb3d/application-insights-think-time?forum=ApplicationInsights).

The answer provided there:
"At this point - we do not have plans on supporting arbitrary think times. We ourselves, and some customers work around this by calling a controller that can take a parameter on the duration it waits on before responding, from the web test.

Hope this helps.
"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12678288)

Comment: @hveiga, thanks, I added the essential part of the answer into the post.